# Global temporary table in SQL Server is dropped when all connections are closed

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

Maybe I've misunderstood the meaning of global temporary tables in SQL Server (the ones with `##` at the start of the name). I've got a certain number of applications that use the same database. I need a temporary table that is created by the first application that does the connection to the DB and is dropped only when all the applications disconnect from DB (a connection is always kept opened in the main thread). All the applications can write on and read from this table.

Using the global temp table I can partially achieve the result. The temp table is indeed created only by the first application and is used by the others. But if I close the first application (the one who created the global temp table) it is destroyed.

Is there a way to keep it alive until all the connections are released?

Comment: A global temp table is visible to other users, but only lives as long as your session, or any other sessions accessing it, are open.  Why do you want to use a temp table for this?

Comment: It is possible to create a table in tempdb with create table. and it will stay there until restart etc. Sounds like a bad architecture though.

Comment: We would like to use a temp table instead of a phisical one because it stores information about locked resources (specific of our business domain) to manage concurrency with a pessimistic locking. This approach, you know, could cause deadlocks if the locking mechanism is not reliable and doesn't remove the locked resources at the end. We would like to (partially) avoid this using a temp table, so the locks are deleted when all the applications are closed. Any better approach or suggestion is accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesZ, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: When I have done this kind of locking mechanisms, I have a normal table and end of validity time in the record, which can be minutes or hours depending on the case. Then a batch run that clears expired rows from the table. Since database restart happens so rarely I don't really see any point on relying on that, and having something like that in tempdb just hides the issues instead of fixing it.

Comment: Indeed, we exactly implemented the "expire date" you suggested. To be precise, we store a "creation date" and the expiration period (parametrized) is passed to a stored procedure that clears the expired rows. With a good parametrization we hope to avoid long deadlocks.